# how to calculate the local time from gmtoffset

Tags: python, timezone

im using this wrapper ([pyipinfodb](https://github.com/sonicrules1234/pyipinfodb/blob/master/pyipinfodb.py)) for [ipinfodb API](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php). I just want to know how to calculate the local time from IP based in this response:

```
{u'City': u'San Diego',
 u'CountryCode': u'US',
 u'CountryName': u'United States',
 u'Dstoffset': u'0',
 u'Gmtoffset': u'-25200',
 u'Ip': u'76.192.218.153',
 u'Isdst': u'1',
 u'Latitude': u'32.7977',
 u'Longitude': u'-117.132',
 u'RegionCode': u'06',
 u'RegionName': u'California',
 u'Status': u'OK',
 u'TimezoneName': u'America/Los_Angeles',
 u'ZipPostalCode': u''}
```

this is the web client for this IP: http://ipinfodb.com/ip_locator.php?ip=76.192.218.153 and is returning a calculared TimeZone and LocalTime.

Any suggestion? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
import datetime

#parse json to get offset(import json; json.load(resonse); etc.)
#offset is gmtoffset + dstoffset
datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds = offset)
```

Note that this will be the local time of the ip at the moment you execute utcnow.

Code would have to be modified to the time on the response header if you wanted the local time at the moment the api call answered.